# Modeling switch and wild card option for a Treasury futures contract

Tags: fixed-income, futures, treasuries

I understand how to think about the switch option and wild card option in Treasury futures. I know how to model them and get a fair value separately. However, I do not think you can simply just add the two values together to get the option value. Then if you layer in timing option, I imagine this will get fairly complicated.

What is the best practice for modeling these options collectively?